# Yii2: ActiveQuery use relations

Tags: activerecord, yii2

I have 3 tables

> certificates, user, status

they have these relations:

```
certificates - user, one -- many
user-status, one -- one
```

I have activeQuery too:

```
$this->andWhere(['<', 'created', new Expression("DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL " . $days . " DAY)")])
            ->andWhere(['is_active' => 1])
            ->andWhere(['<', 'delayed_until', new Expression("NOW()")])
            ->andWhere(['<', 'resend_count', LeCertificate::RESEND_COUNT])
```

is there is possible to **add scope `->andWhere` where i can get `status.not_deleted = 0` for current certificate?**

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have defined correct relations in `LeCerificate` and `User` classes:

```
LeCertificate::find()->alias('C')
    ->joinWith(['users', 'users.status S'], false, 'INNER JOIN')
    ->andWhere(['<', 'C.created', new Expression("DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL " . $days . " DAY)")])
    ->andWhere(['C.is_active' => 1])
    ->andWhere(['<', 'C.delayed_until', new Expression("NOW()")])
    ->andWhere(['<', 'C.resend_count', LeCertificate::RESEND_COUNT])
    ->andWhere(['S.not_deleted' => 0]);
```

Relations should looks like follows:

```
class LeCertificate extends ActiveRecord 
{
    ...

    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::className(), ['certificate_id' => 'id']);
    }

    ...
}
```

and

```
class User extends ActiveRecord 
{
    ...

    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Status::className(), ['id' => 'status_id']);
    }

    ...
}
```